# Why file doesn't get deleted after using another button

Tags: java, file, exception

Im editing.I also have found It cannot be deleted after using the other button because it throws java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 2018 June Saturday 30 09hr19min37sec.txt: The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process.Which code part of the second button causes the system to keep reading or accesing the file so the first button for delete cannot delete the file?
I have a button that deletes a selected file from a combo box and another button that displays the month profit. The problem is that when I click on the borrar(delete) button it correctly deletes the selected file but when I click the Ventas del mes(Month profit) button and then I want to click the borrar(delete) button again it doesn't delete the selected file from the combo box. This only happens every time I click the delete button after clicking the month profit button.How can i solve this problem?

```
Set<String> results = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> Año = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> Mes = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> Dia = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> textos = new HashSet<String>();
String[] meses = {"enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre",};
Set<String> meses1 = new HashSet<String>();
File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\SATELITE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Restaurante").listFiles();
   public Recibos() {
    initComponents();

    for (File file : files) {
        for (int i = 0; i < meses.length; i++) {
            if (file.getName().contains(meses[i])) {
                meses1.add(meses[i]);
            }
        }
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().contains(".txt")) {
                results.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    DefaultComboBoxModel DefaultComboBoxModel2 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(meses1.toArray());
    cbMes.setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel2);
}
```

Then I have the first button

```
private void btnBorrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtMostrar.setText("");
    results.clear();
    System.out.println(results);
    String text = cbRecibo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    File[] files = new File("C:\\Users\\SATELITE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Restaurante").listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().equals(text)) {
                Path p1 = Paths.get(text);
                try {
                    java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(p1);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Recibos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                System.out.println(file + "xd1");
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(results+"results");
    File[] files2 = new File("C:\\Users\\SATELITE\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Restaurante").listFiles();
    for (File file : files2) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            if (file.getName().contains(".txt")) {
                System.out.println(file + "xd2");
                results.add(file.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(results);
    cbRecibo.removeAll();
    DefaultComboBoxModel DefaultComboBoxModel1 = new DefaultComboBoxModel(results.toArray());
    cbRecibo.setModel(DefaultComboBoxModel1);
}
```

And the second button which after clicking, it causes the first button doesn't delete like it should.

```
private void btnVentasMesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    suma = 0;
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> iterator = results.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String setElement = iterator.next();

        File file = new File(setElement);
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (text.contains("Total")) {
                    list.add(text);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }


    //good way:
    Iterator<String> iterator2 = list.iterator();
    while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
        String setElement = iterator2.next();
        String numberOnly = setElement.replaceAll("[A-Z,a-z,:]", "");
        suma = suma + Double.parseDouble(numberOnly);


    }

    String totalDeVentas = "La venta total del mes de " + cbMes.getSelectedItem().toString() + "\n fue de :" + suma;
    txtMostrar.setText(totalDeVentas);

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved it.I didn´t close this reader

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
reader.close();
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This would be better if you used `try-with-resources`

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
if (file.getName().equals(text)) {
     file.delete();
}
```

But it looks like you are also swallowing any errors

```
 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
```

change to

```
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I have corrected it.I also have found It cannot be deleted after using the other button because it throws java.nio.file.FileSystemException: 2018 June Saturday 30 09hr19min37sec.txt: The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process.Which code part of the second button causes the system to keep reading the file so the first button delete cannot delete the file?